# Specify separating character when deconstructing Object with Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serilog

When deconstructing complex object with the `@` character in Serilog it defaults to using a ":" (colon) as a separating character. I'd like it to be "=" (equal) sign instead. Is this possible?

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
    
public class myClass
{
   public void myMethod()
   {
      var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo().EventLog("myapp");
      var myComplexObject = new 
      {
         property1 = "prop1",
         property2 = "prop2"
      };
      logger.Information("{@complex}", myComplexObject);
   }
}
```

output:

```
{ complex:{ property1:"prop1", property2:"prop2" }}
```

desired output:

```
{ complex:{ property1="prop1", property2="prop2" }}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Note: I know this doesn't follow JSON format. We have a requirement to structure logs in event logs in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of methods is custom `ITextFormatter`

```
namespace WebApplication7
{
    public class CustomJsonFormatter : ITextFormatter
    {
        private readonly JsonValueFormatter _valueFormatter = new JsonValueFormatter(typeTagName: null);

        public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write("{");

            var precedingDelimiter = "";

            foreach (var property in logEvent.Properties)
            {
                output.Write(precedingDelimiter);

                output.Write("\"");
                output.Write(property.Key);
                output.Write("\":");

                // Replace colons with equal signs in the property value
                var valueWriter = new StringWriter();
                _valueFormatter.Format(property.Value, valueWriter);
                var valueString = valueWriter.ToString().Replace(":", "=");

                output.Write(valueString);

                precedingDelimiter = ",";
            }

            output.Write("}");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in appsetting.json

```
"WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
              "path": "/logs/log-.txt",
              "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
              "formatter": "WebApplication7.CustomJsonFormatter,WebApplication7",
              "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
        }
      //........
```

now the output will show the format what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your customized formatting. You can create it by inheriting the `ITextFormatter` interface.

[Documentation of Custom formatters](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#custom-formatters)